# How to get the closest nodes in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Based on the model here, I am trying to find the closest meeting room based on the proximity of the rooms in this model. I wanted to the results like this,

```
+-------+----------+--+
| Room  | Distance |  |
+-------+----------+--+
| room1 |        3 |  |
| room2 |        3 |  |
| room3 |        4 |  |
| room4 |        4 |  |
+-------+----------+--+
```

My model:

[image: Model]

I have tried this query:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:"test"})-[r*2..]->(f:Floor)<-[:ROOM_LOCATED_IN_FLOOR]-(r:Room)
RETURN p, f, r
```

which just gives the meeting rooms the person is located. But I wanted to traverse through other rooms in different floors.

Comment: How do you define distance? The room on the closest floor?

Comment: I have tried this query 

MATCH (p:Person {name:"test"}) -[r*2..]->(f:Floor)<-[:ROOM_LOCATED_IN_FLOOR]-(r:Room) RETURN p,f,r 

which just gives the meeting rooms the person is located. But i wanted to traverse through other rooms in different floors.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas yes . you are right

Comment: @GaneshChippada edit your question to add more details instead of comment on it. I answered your question, please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a sample data for testing:

```
CREATE (p:Person)
CREATE (d:Desk)
CREATE (f1:Floor)
CREATE (f2:Floor)
CREATE (r1:Room {name : 'room1'})
CREATE (r2:Room {name : 'room2'})
CREATE (r3:Room {name : 'room3'})
CREATE (r4:Room {name : 'room4'})

CREATE (p)-[:SEATED_AT]->(d)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(f1)-[:HAS_NEXT]->(f2)
CREATE (f1)<-[:PART_OF]-(r1)
CREATE (f1)<-[:PART_OF]-(r2)
CREATE (f2)<-[:PART_OF]-(r3)
CREATE (f2)<-[:PART_OF]-(r4)
```

Then, you can get the desired result with [size()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size) and [relationships()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) functions:

```
MATCH p = (:Person)-[*]-(r:Room)
RETURN r.name as Room, size( relationships(p) ) as Distance
ORDER BY Distance
```

The output will be:

```
╒═══════╤══════════╕
│"Room" │"Distance"│
╞═══════╪══════════╡
│"room1"│3         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"room2"│3         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"room3"│4         │
├───────┼──────────┤
│"room4"│4         │
└───────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks